# Installing Phalcon on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, phalcon

I've recently been hired to assist a lead developer with a company that uses the PHP framework Phalcon. I'm trying to get familiar with it but I'm having the hardest time getting installed on my system.

I'm running Linux Mint 20.1 and I have php7.4.3.

Here's what I'm getting when I follow the directions here:
https://phalcon.io/en-us/download/linux

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7-phalcon
[sudo] password for garrett:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7-phalcon

$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php7.0-phalcon : Depends: phpapi-20151012 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Okay, here's a new update, before this apt-cache search phalcon yielding nothing, it just came back with a list of results, I installed the one for php 7.4, ouptut is below. But now, when I run phpinfo(); the info page does not list phalcon anywhere, my understanding is that is should.

$ sudo apt install php7.4-phalcon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-pgsql php7.4-memcached
The following NEW packages will be installed:
php7.4-phalcon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 577 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,641 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,960 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/debian stretch/main amd64 php7.4-phalcon amd64 4.1.2-1221+php7.4 [1,641 kB]
Fetched 1,641 kB in 1s (1,106 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package php7.4-phalcon.
(Reading database ... 335907 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php7.4-phalcon_4.1.2-1221+php7.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.4-phalcon (4.1.2-1221+php7.4) ...
Setting up php7.4-phalcon (4.1.2-1221+php7.4) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/phalcon.ini with new version
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10) ...
Processing triggers for php7.4-cli (7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10) ...
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. Apparently you have installed PHP 7.4 and you are trying to install Phalcon for PHP 7. Which version of Phalcon do you want to install?
2. According to your answer, if you want to install Phalcon 4 with PHP 7.4 you first have to install PSR (follow the steps [here](https://github.com/jbboehr/php-psr)) and then follow the steps for Ubuntu/Debian on the installation page that you used. If you want to install Phalcon 3.4 on PHP 7.0 just follow the steps for Ubuntu/Debian (using Packagecloud).